# Improve Precision of Negative class in Neural Network Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, precision, precision-recall

I have trained CNN for predicting the audio tone (Negative, Neutral, Positive) and i have 4 different CNN models with slightly different architecture and datasets. These models are working fine in most of the test cases and provide the expected output.
code:

```
# 0 is for Negative
# 1 is for Neutral
# 2 is for Positive

print(model.predict(x),model.predict_classes(x))
```

The output which i get from all 4 models is below.

```
[[1.0000000e+00 2.4311501e-12 1.3999395e-16]] [0]
[[4.4723673e-04 5.5520708e-08 9.9955267e-01]] [2]
[[5.34977562e-06 1.20891924e-29 9.99994636e-01]] [2]
[[9.9999642e-01 2.8299738e-24 3.6233271e-06]] [0]
```

What i want to do is to provide more weight to Positive and Neutral class predictions neuron so that my model is more inclined towards predicting the Positive and Neutral output than Negative output. I want to know what would be the right way of manipulating the probabilities so that the model only outputs Negative when its 100% sure that its Negative. So, i want my Model to be more precise when predicting Negative class as compared to other classes, while incorporating the probabilities of all 4 models equally in the final prediction.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loss function to `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits()`

Comment: I was about to use it but then I saw it mentioned unbalanced data which threw me off because my data is balanced so, I thought I could set some threshold once i get the prediction scores from all these models to get desired functionality and i wouldn't have to train the models again.